# After using a UDF Excel Stops Working during save

Tags: vba, excel

I have set up a keyboard shortcut (`ctrl`+`alt`+`c`) That calculates the users selection pretty basic I grabbed off of here

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnKey "^%c", "CalculateSelection"
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub CalculateSelection()
On Error GoTo NoSelection

If Not Selection Is Nothing Then
  If TypeName(Application.Selection) = "Range" Then
  Dim Rng As Range
  Set Rng = Application.Selection
  Rng.Calculate
 End If
End If

Exit Sub
```

NoSelection:
    MsgBox ("No Range Selected")
End Sub

This works perfectly fine on all other cell and i can save my work when its all completed.

> If I use this function on a cell that calls an API the function works fine until you save, Microsoft stops working entirely and I have no idea why.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? would this be cause by some object not being destroyed or is my excel corrupt?

All the API function work fine I've had no errors with them until I used this sub on them.

This is the function that sends the data to the API. It has different functions that are called from the sheet to format the data to XML and check whether the data being passed is correct and fully calculated.

```
Private Function PostToApiXmlToXml(Data As String, Route As String)

'Initialise Document Object Model to hold the XML
'And the xmlHttp to handle Sending Data
Dim xmlhttp As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Dim XMLDOM As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
Set XMLDOM = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

'Load entire Document before moving on
'Data is a string but must conatin opening and closing tags.
XMLDOM.async = False
XMLDOM.LoadXML (Data)

'Using the Http object
With xmlhttp
    Call .setOption(2, SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS)
    'Set up a POST to the Base Address + Route
    .Open "POST", BaseAddress + Route, False
    'Content-Type Header is requred to let the API Know What type of Data you are Sending
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/xml"
    'Accept Header Lets the Api know we want to recieve JSON Data
    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    'Send the Dom as XML in the http object
    .send (XMLDOM.Xml)
    'Take in the Response as text
    PostToApiXmlToXml = .responseText
End With

Set xmlhttp = Nothing

End Function
```

I can use the keyboard shortcut anywhere on the sheet and save with no problems. and i can use it on single cells with API calls and press `ctrl` + `s` and it saves fine. But if i select multiple and press `ctrl` + `alt` + `c` then save with `ctrl` + `s` it corrupts the save and restores to previous save doesn't let me open or view any of the problems with the corrupted version.

Comment: Can you post the API, or the relevant save portion of that code?  Also, what's the rest of your function look like?